# jquery ui autocomplete json

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery autocomplete not working with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234455/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-with-json-data)

I'm trying to get the autocomplete and json to work, I've spent hours trying various things, but keeping it simple such as this was the closest I got it to work:

```
$('#group_id').autocomplete({
    source: "/ajax/groups"
});
```

Adding all the other params doesn't seem to help.

As I type, I notice a small drop down appearing, but there is no text inside, it's just blank. Various other methods I try, the drop down does not show up at all. I also thought this would solve the problem, but it doesn't: [JSON for Jquery autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184818/json-for-jquery-autocomplete)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I found out the answer after even more random searching with the help of this answer: [jquery autocomplete not working with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234455/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-with-json-data)

Apparently I didn't have my key named as "label" or "value", it's working now!