# trouble understanding json and jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: json, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jquery-ui autocomplete and I'm having trouble fully understanding how to hook it up.

In an effort to see functionality, we exported a list of user names in the json format of

```
["Abbott, Bob", 
"Adams, Jo", etc...
```

and it's over 8k lines.  I saved this into a file called names.json.  When I set up my autocomplete, I used the following:

```
$("#userName").autocomplete({
  source: "names.json"
});
```

Based on the [jqueryi-ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) page.  It says this:

```
When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data.
```

It returns all 8k+ names instead of filtering it based on what I'm typing.  I tried changing it to:

```
$("#userName").autocomplete({
  source: "names.json?term="
});
```

That didn't work to filter it either.

I've tried variations on the remote JSONP datasource example, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried changing my json file to the format of:

```
[{"value":"Abbot, Bob"},
{"value":"Adams, Jo"}, etc...
```

That didn't filter.

I've tried taking out the quotes around value.  That didn't return anything.

I've tried changing it to the format listed in the answer for [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184818/json-for-jquery-autocomplete) returning item.value with my second json format but that didn't filter it either.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and I hope to understand.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datasource needs to by dynamic.

jquery ui autocomplete is going to send a request to the URL you have specified with `?term=WHATEVER_THE_USER_TYPED` appended. You need something on the server side that will process that request and return just the data for that term.

For instance,

```
$("#userName").autocomplete({
    source: "names.php" // php as an example.
});
```

Will result in a request to:

```
/names.php?term=abcd
```

names.php would have to pull back the data that matches the search and return it.

Comment: Ah, so the fact that the page is static is the reason why it returns everything?  Then I need to create the json results with an action and wire it up with Struts 2 before it'll work?